# Display random number in 2d array

Tags: c

I have built a `2D-array` with random number filled in. I am expecting to generate random number between `1` to `7` with a pair each. But I am not sure why some number generated only single number. I have attach the example below.

Here's my code:

```
int gameboard(char box[9][9])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            box[x][y] ='_'; 
        }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        box[0][x]='#';
        box[x][8]='#';
        box[x][0]='#';
        box[8][x]='#';            
    }
}

void rnum(char box[9][9])
{
    int r1,r2,r3,r4,x;
    char r='1',num;
    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); 

    for(x=0;x<7;x++)
    {
        r1 = 1 + rand()%7;
        r2 = 1 + rand()%7;
        r3 = 1 + rand()%7;
        r4 = 1 + rand()%7;

        box[r1][r2]= r + x;
        box[r3][r4]= r + x;
    } 

}
```

Example of output:
[image]

Comment: First thing, compile your code with -Wall option and correct every warning

Comment: Aside: the variable `char name[20];` in function `pname` is an entirely different variable from the `char name[20];` in function `main`, and the input will be discarded. However you don't use the one in `main` which is just as well since it is *uninitialised*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each number are place twice in your code. But you don't care if a number override another one already placed. You have to check if place isn't already selected.

```
for(x=0;x<7;x++)
{
    do
    {
        r1 = 1 + rand()%7;
        r2 = 1 + rand()%7;
    } while(box[r1][r2] != '_');

    box[r1][r2]= r + x;

    do
    {
        r3 = 1 + rand()%7;
        r4 = 1 + rand()%7;
    } while(box[r3][r4] != '_');

    box[r3][r4]= r + x;
}
```

An advice for future: use debugger to find this kind of trouble. Debugger is really useful to run step by step your program and observe value of each variable.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker Yup! :-)

Comment: @user6463380 based on comments from SanderDeDycker, if you affect `box[r1][r2]` before choosing `r3` and `r4`, you don't have to check relation between `r1`,`r2` and `r3`,`r4`. You can also create function because it's really similar code